# What open graph tags are required to get the large images with text overlays to show up?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'd like to add open graph meta data to my site such that links of my site look like the Anthropologie post below, but instead I'm getting a smaller image with text on the right like the Etsy post above it.

These are the open graph tags I'm providing:

```
<meta property="og:type"            content="article" /> 
<meta property="og:title"           content="{{the title of my page}}" /> 
<meta property="og:description"     content="{{the description}}" /> 
<meta property="og:image"           content="{{ the image url}}" />
```

Should I be using a different type? Or is there another opengraph tag I need to provide to get the bigger image to display?

[image]

Comment: `These are the open graph tags I'm providing:` - Why can't I see? :O

Comment: Edited to show the open graph tags.

Answer (score 0):

The **Etsy's** post you have shown is a [**feed**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/feed/),
and the **Anthropologie's** post you've shown is a [**photo**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)

Understand the difference between the two.

Comment: Yes, I understand there is a difference in the two posts. What I'm asking is if there is a way to get my post to look like the second? Is it possible by changing the og:type to "photo"? Or is there no way via open graph tags to get a link to show up like that?